# Bitmap.compress to png - save only if file is in the right size

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, png

I have a jpg that is taken using a camera intent, displayed to the user (with some size adjustments), and eventually saved as png.

I first read the file into a bitmap using
`BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);`

I then reduce the image size (in pixels) using
`Bitmap.createScaledBitmap()`

and eventually I want to save the resized bitmap into a png, using
`FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pngFile);`
`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);`
`fos.flush();`
`fos.close();`

The problem is that the final png file should not exceed a certain size (in bytes). If it does, I would like to continue with resizing the bitmap until my file is small enough.
I can't check it before the png compression (while still a bitmap, using `bitmap.getAllocationByteCount()` - API 19 and up), because the bitmap is always larger than the png, (at least from what I've seen, including some basic tests I tried out in paint), and the png is the one I actually need at the end.

Of course, I can always save the png to the disk, read the length of the saved file, if it's too big read as bitmap, reduce again, save again, etc. But I prefer not to do that...

Is there any other way?

Comment: There are a lot of factors influencing the final PNG size. You may have different options for compression (think "faster" vs. "better"). A tool such as `pngcrush` may be able to crunch out a file as small as possible. But the Flate algorithm, as used in PNG, is unpredictable at root, and you cannot predict how large the output will be without actually compressing.

Comment: @Jongware I don't need the png to be as small as possible (when I say "small" I'm talking about size in bytes, not pixels). It should only be small enough. If it's not - I'll make it smaller (not a problem) until I get to a file small enough. I understand that I have to actually compress it, I just don't want to save it to the disk until I know it's indeed small enough. When I finally get to a png small enough - I'll save that one.

Comment: So you are now physically writing a file (`FileOutputStream`) and checking its size "after the fact"? You don't mention which language you are using (Java?); perhaps you can redirect an output stream to memory instead. It should be faster than writing to a file; when you have a size small enough, you can write it to disk.